# Interpolation of scattered scalar values in 3D volume

Tags: matlab, interpolation, scatter

I have an unknown scalar fonction defined into a partial space (a pyramid portion), for this function, I have several measurements points into the coordonates `mesurePoints`, where the mesure `mesure` is known :

```
size(mesurePoints) = [n 3]
size(mesure) = n
```

I also have my space discretized into a clood of equidistant points wich I'll call `interpolPoints`,

I would like to obtain interpolated values `interp_mesure` on the points `interpolPoints` based on my measurements `mesure` on the points `mesurePoints`.

I tried to use [interp3](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html),

```
interp_mesure = interp3(...
mesurePoints(:,1),mesurePoints(:,2),mesurePoints(:,2),...
mesure,...
interpolPoints(:,1),interpolPoints(:,2),interpolPoints(:,3));
```

but I get the error that V (`mesure`) should be a 3D array, but I am confuse, my data isn't 3D, it is 3D dependant, but it's a scalar data, how can I proceed? Is interpol3 not adapted to my problem?

Edit 1 : Here is a similar problem to illustrate mine : how do you interpolate temperature in a volume if you have some temperature measurements in this volume?

Edit 2 : as no matlab solution have come to mind yet, I use a hand-made interpolation weighted by inverse distance with a power factor, the result is good close to points but as my points are quite scattered, the result is not good in empty areas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding exactly what is your data, but I get the impression that maybe interp1 or interp2 would be better suited to your needs, as your data isn't organized as a 3-D array

Comment: How could I organize my data as 3-D array? It doesn't make sense to me as it is a scalar value associated to space coordonates, and my domain isn't a square, so unless 3D arrays can be pyramidal, wich they are not by design, they don't suit my needs. It is not my problem, but it's similar one to illustrate mine : how would you interpolate temperature in a volume if you know the temperature at some points? First post edited.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your problem better now.

First, take a look at multidimensional arrays: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html

This way, you would organize your "temperature measurements" in a 3D array representing the space, and then you could use interp3 on that.

Comment: Now, for your problem, you say your space is akin to a pyramid. 

However, how is it organized? Is it a series of 2-D matrixes? Because if it were organized in 3-D, you could use interp3, obvisouly...